# CONVERT MySQL Query to SQL Server (MSSQL / SQLSRV) (WiTH DISTINCT)

Tags: mysql, sql-server

What do I need to do to convert this query to work within in SQL Server?

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(map_objetivos.OBJ_RowID) AS test,
    map_objetivos.OBJ_Objetivo
FROM 
    map_admin_caminho_critico_indicadores
INNER JOIN 
    map_admin_caminho_critico ON CCR_RowID = CCI_CaminhoDR
INNER JOIN 
    map_indicadores ON IND_RowID = CCI_IndicadorDR 
INNER JOIN
    map_objetivos ON OBJ_RowID = IND_ObjetivoDR
GROUP BY
    map_objetivos.OBJ_RowID
```

Comment: is it giving you an error? looks good to me. Maybe remove the 2 parenthesis after distinct (leave a space)

Comment: Guessing it's failing because of aggregation errors.

Comment: I suspect its failing because the group by clause doesnt include map_objetivos.OBJ_Objetivo , and nor is it aggregated

Comment: This would give you a "'map_objetivos.OBJ_Objetivo' is not valid in the select list..." aggregation error. Otherwise, the syntax is valid for SQL server.

Comment: DISTINCT always works on all selected fields, no matter how many parenthesis you use. Best to remove those parenthesis because you are confusing yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server, unlike MySQL, won't allow unaggregated or grouped fields in the select list.  Also, your `DISTINCT` is redundant.  Try this:

```
SELECT 
    map_objetivos.OBJ_RowID AS test,
    map_objetivos.OBJ_Objetivo
FROM 
    map_admin_caminho_critico_indicadores
INNER JOIN 
    map_admin_caminho_critico ON CCR_RowID = CCI_CaminhoDR
INNER JOIN 
    map_indicadores ON IND_RowID = CCI_IndicadorDR 
INNER JOIN
    map_objetivos ON OBJ_RowID = IND_ObjetivoDR
GROUP BY
    map_objetivos.OBJ_RowID,
    map_objetivos.OBJ_Objetivo
```

Comment: Thanks @Johan, copied too fast.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    map_objetivos.OBJ_RowID AS test,                 <<-- all non-aggregate fields
                                                     <<-- must be in the group by
    MAX(map_objetivos.OBJ_Objetivo) as OBJ_Objetivo  <<-- put the rest in a dummy
                                                     <<-- aggregate.
FROM 
    map_admin_caminho_critico_indicadores
INNER JOIN 
    map_admin_caminho_critico ON CCR_RowID = CCI_CaminhoDR
INNER JOIN 
    map_indicadores ON IND_RowID = CCI_IndicadorDR 
INNER JOIN
    map_objetivos ON OBJ_RowID = IND_ObjetivoDR
GROUP BY
    map_objetivos.OBJ_RowID
```

This query will run faster than a query with extra fields in the group by clause.
If you want your queries to run fast, you need to only put those fields in the group by that **uniquely define** the selected fields.
Use a MIN() or MAX() aggregate to get SQL-server to stop complaining.
Because the other selected fields are functionally depended on the group by clause, there will only ever be one value per row in the resultset and the MAX() function will not slow you down.

The extra long group by clause will slow your query down.

**Remember to only use this trick if the other fields are functionally dependent on the group by clause**

**About Distinct**
This code:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(map_objetivos.OBJ_RowID) AS test,
    map_objetivos.OBJ_Objetivo
```

Is the same as this code

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    map_objetivos.OBJ_RowID AS test,
    map_objetivos.OBJ_Objetivo
```

You cannot use `DISTINCT` on a single field in the select.
If you want to do **that** use a `GROUP BY` with a single field in a subselect.

```
SELECT f1,f2,f3           <<-- trick to select the first distinct f1 rows.
FROM t1 WHERE id IN (
  SELECT MIN(id) as FirstID FROM t1 
  GROUP BY f1)
```

Comment: @jadarnel27, MySQL forces you to think that way, because it does not require the dummy aggregate.

Comment: **Hi Guy! Thank you for the quick response.
I am working with Doctrine 2.**
$qb =    $em->createQueryBuilder()
->select('obj.objRowid')
->from('MapAdminCaminhoCriticoIndicadores', 'cci')
->innerJoin('cci.cciIndicadordr', 'ind')
->innerJoin('cci.cciCaminhodr', 'ccr')
->innerJoin('ind.indObjetivodr', 'obj')
->groupBy('obj.objRowid')
->getQuery();
**Return correct (grouped) for echo 'objRowid':**
2
4
11
**Now, I insert the column 'cci.cciRowid' in 'select' and 'GroupBy'. Return without group, repeating the value '4 ':**
2
4
4
11

Comment: @WillianTeodoro, I think it's best to ask that in a new question, the comments is not a good place to answer that question.

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping on one field but the second field is notused in an aggregate.  Try the following.

```
SELECT  
    DISTINCT(map_objetivos.OBJ_RowID) AS test, 
    map_objetivos.OBJ_Objetivo 
FROM  
    map_admin_caminho_critico_indicadores 
INNER JOIN  
    map_admin_caminho_critico ON CCR_RowID = CCI_CaminhoDR 
INNER JOIN  
    map_indicadores ON IND_RowID = CCI_IndicadorDR  
INNER JOIN 
    map_objetivos ON OBJ_RowID = IND_ObjetivoDR 
GROUP BY 
    map_objetivos.OBJ_RowID,
    map_objetivos.OBJ_Objetivo
```

Edit: As JNK mentioned - distinct in this case is redundant.

```
SELECT  
    map_objetivos.OBJ_RowID AS test, 
    map_objetivos.OBJ_Objetivo 
FROM  
    map_admin_caminho_critico_indicadores 
INNER JOIN  
    map_admin_caminho_critico ON CCR_RowID = CCI_CaminhoDR 
INNER JOIN  
    map_indicadores ON IND_RowID = CCI_IndicadorDR  
INNER JOIN 
    map_objetivos ON OBJ_RowID = IND_ObjetivoDR 
GROUP BY 
    map_objetivos.OBJ_RowID,
    map_objetivos.OBJ_Objetivo
```