# Convert MYSQL to SQLSRV

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am working on my Excel generator and trying to convert my MYSQL function to SQLSRV. But having issue of finding equivalent functions for some of them. Here is the code:

```
 $result=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno()); 


$file_ending = "xls";
$reals=array();
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < sqlsrv_num_fields($result); $i++) {
    $type = mysql_field_type($result,$i);
    echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
    if ($type == "real")
    {
        $reals[] = $i;
    }
}

print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j=0; $j<sqlsrv_num_fields($result);$j++)
    {
        if(!isset($row[$j]))
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($row[$j] != ""){
            if (in_array($j, $reals)){
                $schema_insert .= str_replace(".",",","$row[$j]").$sep;
            } else {
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            }
        }
        else
            $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\n";
```

Comment: go to this link possible duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893969/convert-mysql-query-to-sql-server-mssql-sqlsrv-with-distinct

Comment: Not the same question. So no duplicate.